# Ruby on Rails Configuration - Plaid Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to integrate the plaid gem into one of my projects. From the docs it says to configure it as such.

https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby

```
Plaid.config do |p|
  p.customer_id = 'Plaid provided customer ID here'
  p.secret = 'Plaid provided secret key here'
  p.environment_location = 'URL for the development or production environment'
end
```

My question is what file should I have this code? Should it go in my application.rb? config.rb? Just want to make sure I'm following convention. Thanks!

Comment: Also for p.environment_location would it just be "http://localhost:3000/" for local development?

Answer (score 2):

You should create this file in `config/initializers` directory with any file name i.e. `plaid.rb`.

FYI: [Using Initializer Files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files).

Comment: Would I have to include plaid.rb file in any other files in order for it to execute or does rails do that automatically? (Woops - I'll read through the docs posted thanks!)

Comment: No, you shouldn't include it to other files.

Comment: Also for p.environment_location would it just be "localhost:3000/"; for local development?